# Ruby: Search record based on predicate - please suggest nicer solutions

Tags: ruby

(I already wrote a solution to the problem below, but would like to ask whether someone could suggest a cleaner solution, more being in the "Spirit" of Ruby).

PROBLEM: I have an (ordered) set of needles, an (ordered) set of elements in a haystack, and a predicate which takes a needle and a haystack element and yields true or false. The task is to find the first needle where there is some haystack element where the predicate is true, and then returns the haystack element. We are not interested in the needle. The needles and the haystack is represented as an Array.

For example, if

```
needles = [17,3,7,121]
haystack = [40,30,70]
```

and the predicate is

```
def p(needle, hay)
  hay % needle == 0
end
```

the result should be 30, because for needle 17, no element in haystack fulfils the predicate, but for needle 3, the second element (30) does.

Here is my implementation:

```
found = nil
needles.find do |n|
  found = haystack.find { |he| p(n,he) }
  break if found 
end
```

What I find a bit unnatural is that I basically throw away the result of the outer `find` and need to carry around the variable `found`, which eventually holds the result. I was looking for a more concise expression, which directly assigns the result to `found`, i.e.:

```
found = ......
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For future reference, questions like this are better posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- as you already have a solution to the problem, but are only seeking opinions on code quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to note is that it's the `haystack` element you want to find, not the `needle`. Therefore, this variable needs to be the one in your outermost loop.

It would then by more idiomatic to use [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to check for the presence of needles which satisfy the predicate, since you really only care about the `true`/`false` return value.

The end result is:

```
haystack.find do |he|
  needles.any? { |needle| p(needle, he) }
end
```

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the question slightly, sorry. If we are *ordering* the needles, and finding the first haystack which satisfies the predicate the "highest-ordered" needle, then we could do:

```
haystack
  .select { |he| needles.any? { |needle| p(needle, he) } }
  .min_by { |he| needles.index { |needle| p(needle, he) } }
```

Or as an alternate (more efficient) solution, how about:

```
haystack.min_by do |he|
  needles.index { |needle| p(needle, he) } || Float::INFINITY  
end
```

This funny use of `Float::INFINITY` is used in case no `needles` match the condition for the `haystack` element, in which case the `index` method returns `nil`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would give a wrong result. Imagine that the first haystack element would match the third needle, then I would get it as a result, even if the, say, second needle would match the last haystack element. Your solution finds the first haystack element matching **some** needle, i.e. all needles are treated equal.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I missed that point. This would have been clearer to me, if you had provided a more complete example showing this scenario. I've updated my answer with two possible solutions.

Comment: Really great solutions, and I have learned now about `min_by`. If we go for efficiency, I should - as you pointed out - use the last version (`haystack.min_by ...`), **and** not go through the whole `needles` array as you suggested, but search only up to (but not including) the needle with lowest index, for which a haystack element has been found already. Unfortunately, this latter optimization makes the code more clumsy again.

Comment: Yeah, there's often a compromise needed between elegant and efficient code. But assuming your `haystack` and `needles` aren't huge, and the `predicate` isn't very computationally expensive, I wouldn't worry about it too much; you'll probably only be saving a few nano-seconds!

Comment: Thanks, I will think about it. Actually, there are around 3 or 4 needles and the haystack is a few thousand elements deep. Unfortunately, this method is called quite often for different parameters to the predicate (around 100000 times in one run), so I think I will do some time measurements, for the safe side. Anyway, thank you for helping.